# Convert JSON null to nan in simplejson.load()?

Tags: python, json, null, nan, simplejson

I have been using the `simplejson` module to correctly handle all NaN --> null conversions (going from python to json). Specifically:

- I've been using the `ignore_nan=True` flag in the `simplejson.dump` function).
- I can't seem to find the equivalent functionality going the other way i.e. **from JSON null to a nan** - with the `simplejson.load` function. The default seems to be to read in the nulls to `None`.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - I ended up making the following function(s) to achieve what I wanted (requires `math` module):

```
def convert(d):
    if isinstance(d,dict):
        yield {k:v for k,v in dict_convert(d)}
    elif isinstance(d,list):
        yield list_convert(d)
    else:
        yield d 

def list_convert(d):
    return [math.nan if i is None else i for i in d]

def dict_convert(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        yield key, [i for i in convert(value)][0]

#d_in = JSON data, containing nulls
#d_out = JSON data, with null converted to nan

d_out = [i for i in test_opennem.convert(d_in)][0]
```

Seemed to work for any `d_in` JSON structure for me, (no matter how many nested components)... Though not widely tested, and probably not suit all cases etc.

Also only converts null values in a list to NaN, (not dictionary keys or other strings to NaN) - which was also fine in my case.